# Regex to detect urls without www and http

Tags: javascript, regex

Could you update my regex to match with next requirements

- Must match urls without www and http
- If query contains - match too
- Url ends when space or comma(,) or string end meet
- match only with TopLevelDomains from list

  ```
  var srg = new RegExp(/(^|[\s])([\w\.]+\.(com|cc|net))/ig);
  ```

For sample, must match:

```
jsfiddle.net
jmitty.cc:8080/test3s.html
www.ru,sample.com,google.com/?l=en
very.secure.dotster.com/i?ewe
```

As result i need

```
<a>jsfiddle.net</a>
<a>jmitty.cc:8080/test3s.html</a>
<a>www.ru</a>,<a>sample.com</a>,<a>google.com/?l=en</a>
<a>very.secure.dotster.com/i?ewe</a>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tYnU7/

Comment: There's no negative lookbehind in JS :(

Comment: _match only with TopLevelDomains from list_ yet you're accepting `www.ru` as noted in your desired result...

Comment: Just wanted to add to @mishik's comment, I use [Regexpal](http://regexpal.com) to test JS regex's. A lookbehind assertion does not work in JS, so a '(?<=a)b' will not match the letter 'b' in the work 'abomination'. But it'll work for non JS regex's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess you can change some little things in your regex:

```
([\w\.]+\.(?:com|cc|net|ru)[^,\s]*)
```

Replace by:

```
<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>
```

I'm not sure why you were having `(^|[\s])` at the beginning and it didn't seem useful to me, so I removed it. If you had your reasons, you can put it back.

I added `ru` to the extensions to match `www.ru` as you required and added `[^,\s]*` to continue matching until a comma or space is encountered.

Your updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tYnU7/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex problem with no perfect answer, but if you don't need perfection, check out Jeff Roberson's [Linkify](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/linkifyurl/linkify.html) page and [this post](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/) by Van Goyvaerts discussing Jeff Atwood's blog post, "The Problem with URLs".

Answer (score 0):

```
/
  (?:^|\b)             # match word boundary or beginning of line
  (                    # begin cpature
    [\w.]+               # domain part
    \.[a-z]{2,3}         # domain suffix
    (?:\:[0-9]{1,5})?    # optional port
    (?:\/.*)?            # path details
  )                    # end capture
  (?:[,\s]|$)          # comma, space or eol
/ig
```

Some details:

- `[\w.]+` may need more work depending on what you classify as acceptable domain characters (I've heard they're accepting unicode characters now?)
- You can change `[a-z]{2,3}` in to a list of acceptable top-level domains (e.g. `(?:com|org|net|info|edu)`. In your example you only list com, cc & net, but your result shows `www.ru` as captured.
- `(?:\/.*)?` is greedy by default, but should be okay since you *want* query information.

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYnU7/3/)

Oh, and if you want your links clickable (because those without a protocol don't work):

```
var r = t.replace(srg, function(match,b,m,e){
    return b + '<a href="'+ (m.indexOf('http') == -1 ? 'http://' : '') + m + '">' + m + '</a>' + e;
});
```

Which is demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tYnU7/4/)